Blazor with SignalR using scoped CSS isolation results in 404
In my Blazor SignalR WebApp the scoped CSS isolation is not working. So, I created a new "Blazor Server App Empty" using the VS template to be sure not having a misconfiguration and added just the stylesheet links in _Host.cshtml. I always get 404 for the css.
Here is the code - Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();

MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<main> @Body </main>

App.razor:
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

_Imports.razor:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using EmptyBlazorApp1

Pages\Index.razor:
@page "/"
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Pages\_Host.cshtml:
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace EmptyBlazorApp1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    
@* Problem : Non of the links works. All returning 404 *@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="EmptyBlazorApp1.styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/EmptyBlazorApp1/EmptyBlazorApp1.bundle.scp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/EmptyBlazorApp1.styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_framework/EmptyBlazorApp1.styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_framework/EmptyBlazorApp1/EmptyBlazorApp1.bundle.scp.css" />

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

All links are causing 404 errors:

I also tried adding builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets(), but I still http 404 errors.
Are Blazor SignalR web apps not compatible with CSS isolation?

Hi jaz, could you kindly check the answer below, please let me know if it works for you. Thanks

After checking the issue, I found we should add a .razor.css file Enable CSS isolation. In my sample project, I create a Index.razor.css, and it works well.



If not using the .razor.css file.



Hi Jason. Thanks for answering. With your changes, the problem for  empty-blazor-app is solved. My problem is, that my setting is more complex. I have a net8-win console-app linking a net8-win aspcore-lib. The console is calling the aspcore-lib to launch kestrel in background. The css-bundles are now compiled as I can see them in "obj\Debug\net8.0-windows\scopedcss" with correct naming. However also with Index.razor.css, the css won't be found. Maybe because the entry-assembly is the console-app? Maybe because kestrel runs in a lib?

I tried to enhance the empty-blazor-app above with a console-app to have the same setting, but I get a strange error "InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.". So I'm currently not able to do that...

Hi @jaz, this is another issue, could you post a new thread with asp.net-core tag ? Then we can focus on that issue.
